# How to find the recent date

Tags: sql

**Data :**

```
id  |status| Date   | what_i_need
------------------------------- 
1   |C     |Jan-15  |Jan-15
1   |C     |Feb-15  |Feb-15
1   |D     |Mar-15  |Feb-15
1   |D     |Apr-15  |Feb-15
1   |C     |May-15  |May-15
1   |C     |Jun-15  |Jun-15
1   |D     |Jul-15  |Jun-15
1   |D     |Aug-15  |Jun-15
```

Need to capture the `max date` when the `status` changes to `D`.

What I tried :

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Status, t.Date,
CASE
WHEN status = 'D' THEN d.last_current ELSE t.date END AS what_i_need
FROM table t
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT id, MAX(date) as last_current
FROM table t
WHERE status = 'c'
GROUP BY id) d on d.id= t.id
```

The error with the top part is it is returning the below result :

```
id  |status| Date   | what_i_need
---------------------------------- 
1   |C     |Jan-15  |  Jan-15
1   |C     |Feb-15  |Feb-15
1   |D     |Mar-15  |jun-15  <----This is wrong should be Feb 15
1   |D     |Apr-15  |jun-15  <----This is wrong should be Feb 15
1   |C     |May-15  |May-15
1   |C     |Jun-15  |Jun-15
1   |D     |Jul-15  |Jun-15
1   |D     |Aug-15  |Jun-15
```

Comment: Could you show what you're hoping the resultset will look like?

Comment: @AlexWeinstein Formated

Comment: @AdrianLynch the result set is the last column(what_i_need column)

Comment: Welp, that `id` column is pretty worthless, eh?

Comment: @nhgrif just used for outer join ,nothing to do with logic

Comment: How would your inline view even return anything? There are no values of `status` equal to `'current'`. Or is `'C'` really `'current'`?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia sory about that it was C,updated

Comment: As there is only one ID in your sample data, there is no way that the `what_i_need` column would return anything more than one unique date. Can you put this together on sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: Ah, I get what you what, the key being `when the status changes to D` (in order of date, I imagine). What database are you using?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Which database server are you using? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

I would describe what you need as the most recent date (including the current one) when the status is not `'D'`.  That at least explains the last column.

I would use a correlated subquery for this logic:

```
select t.*,
       (select max(t2.date)
        from table t2
        where t2.date <= t.date and
              t2.status <> 'D'
       ) as what_i_need
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Date` is unique you can use a self join and conditional aggregation to get the last date when status was not D

```
select t.id, t.status, t.date,
max(case when t2.status <> 'D' then t2.date end) what_i_need
from table t
join table t2 on t2.date <= t.date
group by t.id, t.status, t.date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, SQL Server, or PostgreSQL, you can use analytic functions:

```
select id,
       status,
       dt,
       case when status <> 'D' then dt
         else lag(max_dt_grp, grp) over(order by dt)
          end as what_i_need
  from (select x.*,
               max(case when status <> 'D' then dt end) over(partition by id, grp) as max_dt_grp
          from (select x.*,
                       row_number() over(order by dt) -
                       row_number() over(partition by id, status order by dt) as grp
                  from tbl x) x) x
 order by dt
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63bce5/7/0

(I changed your field names to avoid reserved words)